# Equation of an $(n-2)-$sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, spheres

I am looking for the equation of an $(n-2)$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ generated from the intersection of the $(n-1)$- sphere $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = r^2$, and the hyperplane perpendicular to a given vector $ \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and containing the point $(0,0,\ldots,0)$.

I just need some hint to solve this problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it just one equation? We can look at $n-2$ spheres as an intersection of an $n-1$ sphere and a hyperplane.

Comment: @TheKindCat, Thanks for the point. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The additional condition is $\mathbf{v}\cdot (x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$.